# Query Google Sheet with date

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qMarTzWRzfGdX9i3irtpms94jpv6hVvRqUSoP7-rdwE/edit?usp=drive_link), Sheet Data **record** all event date and title, Sheet **Today Event** show all today event,

In sheet data, there are 3 records
18-08-2023  Event A
19-08-2023  Event B
20-08-2023  Event C

I make a query at TodayEvent!A2 **=QUERY(Data!A1:B, "SELECT A, B WHERE A = TODATE(NOW())", 0)** but don't know why only the 19-08-2023 be queried when time is 20-08-2023 00:28:00, timezone of sheet is GMT+8.

Please advise how I can query to correct records when dealing with date/time records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=filter(Data!A:B,Data!A:A=today())
```

***OR***

```js
=QUERY(Data!A:B,"WHERE A=date'"&text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",)
```

[image]

Comment: what is I want only filter the same month and day without the year ?